# Poisson process problem concerning buses

Tags: probability, poisson-process

I am not sure how to approach this problem. For the first part how do I deal with time? Do I consider the probability of no buses arriving within an hour? Do I consider lambda to be 1/15 here?

A bus route in a large town has one bus scheduled every 15 minutes. Traffic conditions in the town are such that the arrival times of buses at a particular bus stop may be assumed to follow a Poisson process. Mr. James arrives at the bus stop at 12 midday to find no bus at the stop. He intends to get on the first bus to arrive.

**1) What is the probability that the first bus will not have arrived by 1:00 pm the same day?**

The first bus arrived at 1:10 pm but was full, so Mr. James was unable to board it.

**ii. What is the probability that at least two more buses will arrive between 1:10 pm and 1:20 pm.**

Comment: Where does $\frac 1{15}$ come from?  If you expect one bus every $15$ minutes, how many do you expect in an hour?

Comment: 4 buses? Not sure if I'm on the right track

Comment: Yes, $4$.  One of the great beauties of the Poisson process is that it really does scale like that.  That is, if you have a Poisson process with mean $1$ over $15$ minutes, then you have a poisson process with mean $4$ over an hour, and so on.

Comment: I am still not sure if I understand. Then lambda is 1/15 overall. And for (1) it's just:  e^(-1/15)*(60) where n=0 (since no bus arrive in that interval)?

Comment: I don't understand where $\frac 1{15}$ is coming from.  That would be relevant if you were counting the number of buses every minute, but you are not.  Since you are counting the buses every hour, $\lambda=4$.

Comment: I meant that if we just consider lambda from the first sentence without considering or solving (1) it's 1/15 right? I plugged this value into P(X(t)=n)=(λt)^n *e^(-λt) / n! .This yields e^(-4) which is the answer for Part (1) - is that correct?

Comment: Also for part (2) is it 1- (e^2/3)-(2/3*e^2/3) for the 10-min interval? Am I doing this right?

Comment: I don't understand.  It's all a question of what you are measuring.  If I want to study the number of buses in a random minute, I'd use $\lambda= \frac 1{15}$.  If I wanted to study the number in a random $15$ minute interval, I'd use $\lambda=1$.  If I wanted to study the number in a random hour, I'd use $\lambda=4$.  And so on.

Comment: Ah, I think you are trying to force the data into some formula you have in mind.  That's why that "$t$" appears.  In that case, sure.  Note that $\frac 1{15}\times 60=4$ so we are saying the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

As already noted in a period of 1 hour your distribution is $Po(4)$ thus the probability that the first bus arrive not early then 1 pm is the probability that 0 buses arrive in the period so

$$P(X=0)=e^{-4}$$

Can you proceed by yourself for the 2nd question?

EDIT: your answer for the 1st question is correct. For the 2nd one it's correct too...but there's an obvious typo. The correct one is

$$1-\frac{5}{3}e^{-\frac{2}{3}}$$

Comment: Thank you.
For part (2) I tried: 1- (e^2/3)-(2/3*e^2/3) given the 10-min interval. Is this correct?